# facebook いいねダイアログのz-indexについて

Tags: facebook

`.fb-like iframe {z-index: 999;max-width: none !important;overflow: visible;}`

を指定してみたり、ほぼ全ての要素にz-indexを指定したりしてみたのですが、どうしてもコンテンツの下に隠れてしまいます。

また覆っている要素にはz-indexは指定していません。（z-index : 0では変化なく、z-index:-1ですとbackgroundに隠れてしまいました。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どなたか解決策をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら宜しくお願いいたします。